# Laravel / Php Carbon Error : Trailing Data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, php-carbon

A piece of code that was working fine has now completely thrown me an error that I'm at a lost of figuring out.
I'm trying to retrieve a bunch of rows and return them.

The error I'm receiving is

> InvalidArgument
>
> Exception Trailing data

in

> vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php:623

I have seen issues where this is happening on PGSQL and with relation to a date format.
However, in my case it's a bit different.
My DB is MYSQL.

Below is the method I have.

```
public function listall()
{
$questions = Question::select('id as qId','questionText','questionCategory','answerType','display','questionOrder','created_at','updated_at')->where('display',1)->orderBy('questionOrder')->with('options')->get();
//$questions = Question::where('display',1)->orderBy('questionOrder')->with('options')->get();

foreach($questions as &$question){
    $number = Answers::where('questionId', $question->id)->get();
    $question->delete = $number->count() == 0 ? true : false;
}

$data['questions'] = $questions;
$data['categories'] = $this->categories;
$data['answerTypes'] = $this->answerTypes;

return $data;
```

}

If I do a dd() instead of the return, I can see all data with no errors.
Which means the code execution is working as expected.
I get the same error if I try `return json_encode($data);`

Instead of selecting all columns with the *, if I mention individual column names as shown in the first line of the function it work as long as if I don't select the id column.
However, if I select the id column the error gets thrown again.
If I do `select id as qId`, then I don't get any errors.

Why would this be happening?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Laravel framework : 6.18.8

Php : 7.4

nesbot/carbon : 2.32.2

Stacktrace in : https://flareapp.io/share/omwQlo7E#F66

Gist at : https://gist.github.com/elabuwa/f9d00d9806134035fc20ec805a8c6498

Comment: Can you please post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Where do you call this method?

Comment: @Rob : Stack trace at https://flareapp.io/share/omwQlo7E#F66

Comment: @Shizzen83 this is called through the route. Route::get('/listall', 'ControllerName@listall')->name('listall');

Comment: Just a guess but do you have an accessor on the Question or Answer model that's incorrectly creating a Carbon instance?

Comment: No. Both of them just have 2 relationships defined and the table name defined. @Rob

Comment: Are the related models doing `Carbon::createFromFormat()` anywhere?

Comment: No. The app doesn't do anything related with dates. It's happy with the dates in created_at columns. @Rob

Comment: if I remove the 'created_at' and 'updated_at' columns I still get the error. The error goes away if I don't select the id column. or select is as a different name like qId. @Rob

Comment: Gist at https://gist.github.com/elabuwa/f9d00d9806134035fc20ec805a8c6498 @Rob

Comment: You may have milli/microsecond precision in your date columns in your DB but not set in your app. If so, check this page of the doc: https://carbon.nesbot.com/laravel/